# Piping reference for "INSTALL=y sh"

Tags: bash, makefile, sh, piping

I came around [this](https://github.com/visionmedia/git-extras#installation)

With the following command for shell:

```
curl https://raw.github.com/visionmedia/git-extras/master/bin/git-extras | INSTALL=y sh
```

Which results in:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/share': Permission denied
make: *** [install] Error 1
No manual entry for git-extras
```

I am curious to know about this piping for 'INSTALL', which my short googling I only found the example in this github. I would like to know how it could be run with `sudo` and a reference to this sort of piping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSTALL=y sh
```

means to run the `sh` program with the environment variable `INSTALL` set to `y`. You can use sudo as follows:

```
curl https://raw.github.com/visionmedia/git-extras/master/bin/git-extras | sudo INSTALL=y sh
```

Comment: Could you please add some references on the environment variable piping to learn from?

Comment: It has nothing to do with piping, it's just part of the syntax of a shell command. You can put environment variables at the beginning of any command. Read the bash man page. And for sudo, it's in its man page as well -- it allows you to put environment variables before the command.